# Using RandBetween to fill a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, fill

I want to generate a range of random numbers in cells A1:C6 using the `RandBetween` function.

When I try this code

```
Range("A1:C6") = WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(10, 1000)
```

each cell is filled with the same number.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
With Range("A1:C6")
    .Formula = "=RANDBETWEEN(10,1000)"
    .Calculate
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

where `.Value = .Value` part rewrites formulas with their values.

Comment: This. This is the way. Simoco, you're on fire recently. :)

Answer (score 0):

Each cell gets the same value, because you are calling the random function just one time. You need to call the Random function once for every cell, like this:

```
For Each c In Worksheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:D6").Cells
    c.Value = (Round((Rnd() * 990) + 10))
Next
```